# Which method is the best to specify the language of a page?

Tags: html, meta-tags

There seems to be two ways to specify the language of a page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
```

and

```
<html lang="en-us">
```

Which one is the preferred way? I know I could just add both tags but I'd rather not have duplicate content.

Also do both methods use the same locale format (i.e. "en-us" and not "en_US")?

Comment: If you are using HTML5 then use 2nd option -- the 1st one is now deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

The second one is the preferred way. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html The first one is "non-conforming". I couldn't find an exact definition of what that means, but I think it means, "it may work, but you can't rely on it".

They both use the format defined in [BCP47](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt), which uses a dash, not an underscore.

Comment: Actually, HTML4(and XHTML) [uses RFC1766](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1.1) for language formats. I don't have the inclination right now to see if/how different those really are, but adding for the sake of the technical note.

Comment: It should also be noted that Google actually ignores your language specification and instead auto-detects the language. [See answer here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/how-can-i-prevent-google-mistakenly-offering-to-translate-a-page/5073#5073) from a Google employee.

Answer (score 3):

HTML 4 and below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
```

HTML 5 +

```
<html lang="en-us">
```