# Chrome says my website is Serbian...how do I "force" chrome to use english?

Tags: language, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent Google mistakenly offering to translate a page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/how-can-i-prevent-google-mistakenly-offering-to-translate-a-page)

Our website is based in the U.S. and all of our users are in the U.S. and the site is written in english. When we open the page in chrome, an alert comes up "This page is in Serbian...would you like to translate it"? I imagine it is some javascript or other code that is triggering that. Is there a way to force chrome to use "English" as the language?

We tried googling this question but came up with nothing. thx!

Comment: Just a thought, if you hit [Translate], what does it (attempt to) translate?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate question...I didn't see the other one when I posted mine. Thanks @w3d