# German content on English page

Tags: seo, multilingual

Would there be any negative effects from uploading German content (job advertisement) to a page template that's tagged up as being in English?

We will not be able to edit the meta tags to signal that this page isn't in English.

Comment: Meta tags are helpful, but they are no way a 'MUST' have. Just like Google translate, the Googlebot can detect which language the content is written in.

Comment: There isnt a meta tag for language which you could specify that Google would understand in any event.  Google can recognise more than one language on a page. Answer on this question might be useful : http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/how-can-i-prevent-google-mistakenly-offering-to-translate-a-page

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any negative effects if the majority of the content is in English.

According to [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192#1):

> Google uses only the visible content of your page to determine its language. We don’t use any code-level language information such as lang attributes. You can help Google determine the language correctly by using a single language for content and navigation on each page, and by avoiding side-by-side translations.

As a result, I would make sure that all content other than the advertisement is in English.

Comment: You quote Google as saying mixed language confuses them and you draw the conclusion that mixing languages is OK for SEO?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Everything below the line was more of a semantic tip than about SEO. It shouldn't hurt SEO as far as I'm aware. I have removed it to eliminate confusion.